# Rails 3 + Rspec 2 + Autotest: Autotest does not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, autotest

I have installed autotest and Rspec2 but Autotest does not want to run. The folder autotest has not been created (I have created it by hand and added discover.rb) and when I run autotest this is what I get over and oveR:

```
$ autotest
loading autotest/rails_rspec2
style: RailsRspec2


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------




















$
```

I've been using autotest for a long time and now it's dead. Any reason why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What needs to be done depends on the rspec version, but for 2.3 above the instructions from the above mentioned rspec wiki https://github.com/rspec/rspec/wiki/autotest tell you this:
"Make sure you have a .rspec file in the project root. That tells RSpec to tell Autotest to load RSpec’s autotest extension."

You may just create the file like `touch .rspec`
The file need not to have any content, but it must exists.
In case you have rspec-rails installed you can also run `rails g rspec:install` and it will create this file for you. The default content being simply one option `--colour`